# golang reader.Read() can arrived EOF, but reader.ReadAt() read same data in dead loop way, not arrived EOF?

Tags: go, io, reader, stringreader

I'm trying to learn the diff in `io.Reader.Read()` and `io.Reader.ReadAt()`;
And I write two example, the first is `io.Reader.Read()`:

```golang
    reader := strings.NewReader("some text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome text here")

    buf := make([]byte, 64)

    i := 0
    for {
        i++
        if i > 10 {
            break
        }

        n, err := reader.Read(buf)

        if n > 0 {
            fmt.Println(string(buf[:n]))
        }

        fmt.Println(err)

        if err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println("All content is over...")
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
    }
```

and the output is:

```
some text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome t
<nil>
ext here
<nil>
EOF
All content is over...
```

the second example just replace the `Read()` to `ReadAt()`:

```golang
    reader := strings.NewReader("some text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome text here")

    buf := make([]byte, 64)

    i := 0
    for {
        i++
        if i > 10 {
            break
        }

        n, err := reader.ReadAt(buf, 2)

        if n > 0 {
            fmt.Println(string(buf[:n]))
        }

        fmt.Println(err)

        if err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println("All content is over...")
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
    }
```

And the result unexpected not arrived the EOF, and deep loop occured if I cancel times limit:
output:

```
me text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome tex
<nil>
me text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome tex
<nil>
me text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome tex
<nil>
me text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome tex
<nil>
me text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome tex
<nil>
me text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome tex
<nil>
me text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome tex
<nil>
me text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome tex
<nil>
me text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome tex
<nil>
me text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome tex
<nil>
```

I expected the second example code output similar with first code example, just offset 2 bytes. but why the code into dead loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading from an [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) using its `Read()` method, the reader's internal pointer (offset) advances by the number of read (returned) bytes. The next `Read()` call will read bytes from the new, adjusted offset.

When you call `ReadAt()` method, you explicitly provide the offset to read at, the internal pointer / offset of the `io.Reader` is **not** used. And since the buffer you read into is smaller than the available data of the source reader (starting at the given offset), you won't get an `io.EOF`, and you'll just read the same data from the same offset over and over again.

Note that if you increase the buffer:

```
buf := make([]byte, 164)
```

This way all the data available at the source can be read into it, and you'll get an EOF immediately (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/165Xw4oltVn)):

```
me text heresome text heres, ome text heresome text heresome text here
EOF
All content is over...
```